# linux + find + delete file with warning that "file <file_name> is deleted"

Tags: linux, awk, sed, find

We can delete the file with `find` using partial file name

```
find -type f -name '*file_name*' -delete
```

what do I need to add to the above syntax in order to print the message that the file is deleted with full file name?

Comment: Just a *notification* (`-print`) or a request for confirmation from the user (`-ok rm -f {} \;`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` can take multiple "actions", and in fact, they all also work as conditions. `-name "*something*" -delete -print` is the same as `-name "*something*" -a -delete -a -print` where `-a` stands for *and*, and it works in the same short-circuiting logic as the `&&` operator in C, so the latter command/action/test only runs if the previous one succeeds.

So, `-delete -print` would print the names of the files actually deleted:

```
$ mkdir test test/ro ; touch test/foo.txt test/ro/bar.txt; chmod 555 test/ro
$ find test -name "*.txt" -delete -print 
find: cannot delete ‘test/ro/bar.txt’: Permission denied
test/foo.txt
```

If we used `-print -delete`, then the printing would happen first, and `find` would also output the names of the files it couldn't delete.

Or if you want a more verbose output (GNU find):

```
$ find test -name "*.txt" -delete -printf 'deleted: %p\n'
```

We could even do something like this to get a different message for deleted and not deleted files (but of course the usual error message makes this a bit redundant):

```
$ find test -name "*.txt" \( -delete -printf 'deleted: %p\n' -o 
                             -printf "could not delete: %p\n" \)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add `-print` option

```
find -type f -name '*file_name*' -print -delete
```

Or use `-ok` in case you need confirm before deletion (confirmation on each single file)

```
find -type f -name '*file_name*' -ok rm -- {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the full file name while deleting and also if you want to display the full filename before deleting

```
find . -type f -iname "*file_name*"  -print -exec rm -rvf {} \;
```

Comment: Why specify the `-r` (recursive) option to `rm` when you know you’re dealing only with plain files?